# HTML5 Application cache - Web and Offline Data in iOS

Tags: ios, html, caching, html5-appcache

I have a question regarding HTML5 Application cache. Here's the scenario:

I have an app that create records and stores in HTML5 storage. On iOS web browsers, I created a few records, after that I saved the page to my home screen. But when I open the link from my home screen, the data doesn't display.

Is HTML5 storage being stored separately on web and home screen browsing?